Responsive images not working as expected with srcset and sizes
I am setting up a website and wanted to use responsive images. It's working to some degree, but not to the exact calculations that I would expect. I wanted to understand if the way I have been doing calculations to compute sizes is incorrect.
Setup: Using 1 DPR for this test
Mobile: 375px (1 column rendered)
Mobile: 480px (2 columns rendered)
Desktop: 1024px (3 columns rendered)
The layout renders according to the width of a screen. On a low-res mobile, it would only show a single column. On a 480px screen, it renders 2 columns and on an 1024 px it renders 3 columns. No problems so far.
In the past, I had been using hi-res images for all scenarios and my website of obviously slow for mobile devices. So I implemented responsive images using srcset and sizes. Here's my code for the img and I will explain the calculations:
<img src="scroll_images/resized/sanjay_melissa-480.jpg" alt="image unavailable" srcset="
            scroll_images/resized/sanjay_melissa-360.jpg 360w,
            scroll_images/resized/sanjay_melissa-480.jpg 480w,
            scroll_images/resized/sanjay_melissa-820.jpg 820w
            "

sizes="
        (min-width: 360px) calc(100vw - 24px), 
        (min-width: 420px) calc(50vw - 24px), 
        (min-width: 820px) calc(33vw - 24px), 
        100vw
        ">




My image has a border of 5px and spacing of 7 px. That’s 12 px on each edge of the image. So multiply that by 2 to get the total empty space I need to account for when rendering the image. Total empty space here is 24 px.
With a screen width of 360px, 1 image accounts for 100vw and reduce 24 px of blank space. Remaining pixel size is 348px. The browser will look for the next largest image that will fit the size. And thus it picks the image with 360px width.
Problem: With a screen width of 420px, 1 image accounts for 50vw and reduce 24 px of blank space for that image within the 50% viewport. Remaining pixel size is 186. The browser will look for the next largest image that will fit the size. And thus it should pick the image with 360px width however it’s picking the 420 px.
Likewise, with a screen width of 820px, 1 image accounts for 33vw and reduce 24 px of blank space for that image within the 33% viewport. Remaining pixel size is 250. The browser will look for the next largest image that will fit the size. And thus it should pick the image with 360px width however it’s picking the 420 px.
If someone could suggest what I may doing wrong with my calculations or understanding, that would be appreciated.
How am I testing? I am starting with the smallest screen size, refreshing the page and checking on the network to check what image size was loaded. I gradually increase the size and refresh the screen, and again check what image is loaded.
